# Java ArrayList filter by element's properties

Tags: java, arrays, optimization, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` containing `Car` objects and I want to get from that `ArrayList` all the unique names as `String` or just the `Car` objects that meet that criteria.

EG:

```
public class Car {

    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Now I have `carArray` that contains a lot of `Car` objects. 
To get the unique names I am doing something like this:

```
Set<String> setOfNames = new HashSet<String>();

for (Car car : carArray) {
    setOfNames.add(car.getName());
}

for (String name : setOfNames) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Is there a better/faster way to filter an ArrayList by its elements properties?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to get a list with property values from a lot of `Car`s? Or do you want to filter your list of `Car`s? What is the filter criteria then?

Comment: I just tried this code, and this hashset allowed me to have duplicate values inside setOfNames? Can you please explain how are you managing to avoid duplicated using this code. Am i missing some thing?

Comment: @ Fatal: I want a list with property values from a lot of Car objects :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are talking about some properties like features (available in other languages), but not available in java, so the best approach is to use setters and getters. 
So my suggestion is to stick with your code since is working pretty fast :)

Good luck,
Arkde

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to iterate over the list anyways, check each entry and collect it into another collection. If you do the same search multiple times sorting the list by that criteria might be an option.

A side note: if `carArray` is actually a `Car[]` you don't need the cast inside your first loop, just do `for (Car car : carArray)`. If it is an `Object[]` you should rethink your design, since in your loop you assume every entry to be a `Car` anyways.

Comment: Yep, forgot about the cast, sorry.. I will edit my question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Does your set `setOfNames` contains unique values? Because if this is the implementation of `Car` class then you have not overridden the methods of `equals` and `hashCode`, How does hashSet make sure that two objects are identical ?

I guess, you will have to override the equals and hashcode method to make sure that hashset does not contain duplicates.

Comment: Hmm.. that is my real code and everything is alright :). Note that I have a set of Strings not a set of Car objects...

Comment: Ohh Dear GOD !! That was the reason, the hash code and equals function for String class is overloaded by default, so we do not have to overload by ourself....i was going round and round, because in my example I was creating objects of car.